# What are all these databases with funny names?

Tags: sql-server

I help support SQL Server installation that hosts SharePoint and various related services. I never really looked at the database side of things until today when I noticed a whole bunch of databases with what look like GUIDs appended onto the database name. Can someone explain what these are? I tried to google for it but I didn't know what to google for and nothing came up from obvious google searches.
[image: Example of what I am asking about]

Comment: IMO this question belongs to http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can we flag it to be migrated there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharepoint System Databases. And they are pretty self explanatory, or? Search service, secure store, session state - easy to understand.

THe rest is a GUID that is used in case multiple instances are installed - the Guid makes the database name unique.

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for. I knew from the names what each database was but I was missing the part about the GUID. Makes sense now.

Comment: Basically you can install multiple different shaerpoint installs and use one sql server.... and every instance gets it's own database set.... identified by a GUID which is also in the sharepoint configuration. Old concept - and makes REALLY CRAPPY database names ;)

Comment: How would you make the names globally unique, Tom?

Comment: No real alternatives there. Seriously. What I miss mostly is an easy way to replace the GUID with a custom name - often the sharepoint installs will have unique tracking codes from whoever sets them up and it would be nice to replace the GUID's with them. I KNOW it is doable in powershell....